# Lenguaje usado en Hotspot Mikrotik

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estoy modificando los archivos del hotspot pero tengo problemas para entender en que lenguaje están programados estos portales, parece PHP con Javascript, no se la verdad, el punto es que he intentado testear estos archivos desde el XAMPP pero no se muestran correctamente, dejo una muestra del código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="$(link-logout)" name="logout" onSubmit="return openLogout()" style="color: #999">                         
        $(if login-by == 'trial')
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">
                ¡Usted está conectado!
            </h1>
        $(elif login-by != 'mac')
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">
                ¡$(username) usted está conectado!
            </h1>
        $(endif)
            <p style="font-size: 15px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <b style="color: #888888">Bytes enviados / recibidos:</b>

                $(bytes-in-nice) / $(bytes-out-nice)
            </p>

        $(if session-time-left)
                <p style="font-size: 15px;"><b style="color: #888888">Conexión / Restante:</b> $(uptime) / $(session-time-left)
                </p>
        $(else)
                <p>Tiempo de conexion: $(uptime)</p>
        $(endif)
        
        <!--
        $(if blocked == 'yes')
            <p>Estado:
            <div style="color: #FF8080">
                <a href="$(link-advert)" target="hotspot_advert">
                <p>propaganda</p></a>
                <p>exigido</p>
            </div>
        $(endif)
        -->
        
        $(if login-by-mac != 'yes')
            <center>
                <input class="button" id="logout" type="submit" value="Desconectar" onclick="return openLogout()" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            </center>
    
        $(else)
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">
            Desconectado :( Debe <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="toglogin" onclick="sections(this.id)">iniciar sesión</a>
            </h1>
        $(endif)
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

En la pagina oficial de mikrotik donde enseñan como modificar dichos archivos, específicamente en [este apartado](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Customizing_Hotspot#List_of_available_variables) dice:

> Some of the variables use **hard coded http URL**

No se si eso de **hard coded http URL** sea lo que estoy buscando, aunque busqué en la web, no encontré nada específico.

El asunto es que a pesar de que en la pagina se documenta como modificar de manera completa los archivos, no termino de comprender ese "lenguaje", si es que se le puede denominar así.

Comment: Más que un lenguaje, eso parece una plantilla y no te va a funcionar en _localhost_, porque no es un script.

Comment: [Su documentación](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Customizing_Hotspot) te puede ayudar bastante :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hard-code es un término que hace referencia a una mala práctica en el desarrollo de software que consiste en incrustar datos directamente en el código fuente del programa, en lugar de obtener esos datos de una fuente externa como un fichero de configuración o parámetros de la línea de comandos, o un archivo de recursos.

Por otra parte lo que he leído de la documentación y trabajado cambiando algunas plantillas, se usa JavaScript, algunas partes del código aparecen con el símbolo $ como si ocuparas PHP, pero no lo es ,dentro de la documentación te explica como cambiar ese tipo de  código a una forma mas legible o idéntica a JavaScript

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tienes razón, no se entiende lo que quise decir. Reviso la información y la edito.